# Dwarf Fortress Adventure Mode 0.31.25 - Steel or Better Weapons?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-adventure

Is it possible to find Steel (or even Adamantine) weapons / armour **anywhere** (other than starting out as a dwarf)? Iron is alright during the start of the game, but once well-equipped goblin ambush parties start appearing, my attacks seem to bounce off pretty much anywhere.

BTW (and please don't eat me) I do **not** have a fort up yet. I seem to enjoy adventure mode too much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adventure mode, as it exists currently, really only has support for Humans and Human towns. This means that finding Steel weapons (there is nothing better) is quite bothersome. There are two ways you can try to get steel weapons, however.

- Get ambushed by Kobolds

Kobolds steal weapons from other civilizations, so they can have steel weaponry if they've been harassing dwarf civs. However, Kobolds tend to starve during Worldgen currently, so you might want to try adding the [NO_EAT] tag to them if you want a non-dead Kobold civ in the first place.

- Find a Night Creature Lair near a Dwarf City

Night Creaturs go out and raid nearby towns, taking the possessions of their victims back with them. If they raid a Dwarven City, this means they have a possibility of having a stockpile of steel treasure in their lair

Comment: One Q though: Dwarven cities? If only human cities can be supported, does it mean I have to create a fort and hope it's near a kobold camp / night creature den?

Comment: Dwarven cities may not be fully fleshed out (or even reachable) but Worldgen doesn't care about that - they still exist. A dwarf is going to get mauled by a night creature winds up in the creature's lair, not the city. An alternative is to simply modify the RAWs so that dwarves have cities like the humans do (and then you can even buy steel equipment).